# Prove that $~ 60 ^{\circ} ~$ is taken in the parallelogram which takes $~ 60 ^{\circ} ~$ at bottom left and the top left

Tags: geometry, angle

I've drawn the below diagram .

[image]

I have to prove that the  $~ \theta_{}  ~$  takes $~ 60 ^{\circ}  ~$

I 've written the angles in the above diagram which I found so far .

Hints are needed .

Comment: The information given does not seem to determine the parallelogram uniquely. In particular, any angle $0< \theta < 90^\circ$ seems possible. (If you take the middle rectangle and stretch it horizontally, then you get another parallelogram with the same angles at its vertices.)

Comment: Ahhh . I missed that .

Comment: This is true only if it is a rhombus.

Comment: Include the question as it is given in the source with given quantities only.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha tut tut.  Doesn't being given the actual question reduce the artistic challenge in telepathically inferring the problem composer's intent, and then solving the problem?

Comment: I noticed that the each green vector takes a same length .

Comment: So the above diagram is not as same as diagram of the book .

Comment: In that case you deal with a rhombus and $\theta=60^0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the symmetry of the rhombus , the angle which is halved by the diagnol line is 60 degrees.